# Springboot, accessing field from object with Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

Having a bit of trouble with using Springboot to create an API, and understanding how Beans work.

I have three classes, and I have simplified them as much as I can;

### ClassA

```
public class ClassA()
{
    private variable neededVar;

    public ClassA()
    {
        //initialise other variables;
    }

    public start()
    {
        /initialise neededVar;
    }

    @Bean
    public variable getNeededVar()
    {
        return neededVar;
    }
}
```

#### Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    private static ClassA myClass;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        myClass = new ClassA();
        ClassA.start();

        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @Autowired
    private variable neededVar;

    @RequestMapping( "/temp" )
    public string getVar()
    {
        return neededVar.toString();
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the controller, I am not getting the neededVar from the created ClassA object myClass, I'm actually not sure what I'm getting.

I also tried doing it this way, with similar results.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    private static ClassA myClass;
    private static variable myNeededVar;

    @Bean
    public variable getNeededVar()
    {
        return myNeededVar;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        myClass = new ClassA();
        myNeededVar = myClass.getNeededVar();
        ClassA.start();

        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

If anyone could point me in the correct direction of getting the neededVar from the instantiated ClassA in the application into my rest controller (and subsequently all the others I will create), that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- The spring doesn't exactly work in a way you are expecting. You
  should delegate object's lifecycle to spring. i.e. You do not need to manually create `ClassA` object and call its `start` method.
- `@Bean` annotation is used to notify spring that you want to create an object of a class that was not part of spring's `autoscan` mechanism.
- In order to delegate class object management to spring, class should be either annotated with `@Component` or it's other variants such as `@Controller`, `@Service` etc. or you should tell spring how to create object of that class using `@Bean` annotation.

To show how you can use `@Component` and `@Bean`, I'll mark Class A as component and inject `Variable` with `@Bean`.

```
 @Component
    public class ClassA()
    {
         /*
          * Notice this autowired annotation. It tells spring to insert Variable object.
          * What you were trying to do with getNeededVar() is done using Autowired annotation
          */
        @Autowired
        private Variable neededVar;

    }
```

Now tell spring how to create object to `Variable` as it's not marked as `@Component`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

  // This is how you register non spring components to spring context.
  // so that you can autowire them wherever needed
   @Bean
   public Variable variable() { 
      return new Variable();
   }
}
```

Your rest controller code stays as is.
**As `Variable` is registred to spring via `@Bean` in `SpringApplication` class, you don't really need `ClassA`.
You can delete it.**

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @Autowired
    private Variable neededVar;

    @RequestMapping( "/temp" )
    public string getVar()
    {
        return neededVar.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for your response.

I've stripped back my code to only show what's necessary (or I thought was). My ClassA actually does quite a bit and is the "back end" of the application, so I definitely need to instantiate one and get the needVar from that.